# Bootstrapping cassandra with different version and OS

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I have a cassandra 3.0.9 installed in Ubuntu 14 (4 nodes). Can I bootstrap an additional node cassandra 3.11.4 with Linux 2 as the OS?

Answer (score 2):

You can run Cassandra on different Linux versions, but it's recommended to use the same version of Cassandra itself - 3.0 & 3.11 are different series, and use of them together in the same cluster is recommended only during upgrades, when you shouldn't do topology change, etc.

Why not bootstrap 3.0.9 on machine with Linux 2? Or upgrade 3.0.9 cluster to 3.11.4 & then bootstrap new node?

Comment: We will be doing an upgrade from 3.0.9 to 3.11 and we want to run in Linux 2. We need to do this without down time.